# What the difference between tf.convert_to_tensor(np.sin(x)) and tf.math.sin(x)?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Bad english, tried my best
I want to plot derivative of function (for example SIN(x), yeah i know that it is cos but only for example) with the following code

```
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
tensor_x = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(x))
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    f = np.sin(tensor_x)
    f = tf.convert_to_tensor(f)

g_x = tape.gradient(f, tensor_x)

axis[1].plot(tensor_x, g_x)
axis[1].set_title("Derivative of sin")
plt.show()
```

And i have g_x is None!

But if i change this code

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
 f = np.sin(tensor_x)
 f = tf.convert_to_tensor(f)
```

with

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    f = tf.math.sin(tensor_x)
```

everything is fine.

```
#g_x = tf.Tensor(
# [ 0.28366219  0.1855199   0.08548635 ...........
```

What is the difference and why

```
 f = np.sin(tensor_x)
 f = tf.convert_to_tensor(f)
```

didn't work?

In both cases I have tf.Tensor

```
converted_from_np = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.sin(tensor_x))
real_tensor_from_tf = tf.math.sin(tensor_x)

print(type(converted_from_np) == type(real_tensor_from_tf))
real_tensor_from_tf == converted_from_np # True, True, True, ......
```

And the elements of each array is tf.Tensors too.

Comment: Only Tensorflow operations have gradients defined in Tensorflow, not numpy functions.

Answer (score 0):

For computing gradients with `GradientTape`, every transformation function (like computing the cos of x) has to come from TensorFlow. If you use e.g. numpy along the way, TensorFlow has no way of computing the gradients along the way from `g_x` to `tensor_x`, because numpy doesn't provide gradients for TensorFlow for its computations. (why should it? It's not numpys job to provide gradient computation for another library.)
You are correct, that in the end you have a tensor in both cases, but after `f = np.sin(tensor_x)` you have a numpy array, and the gradients for TF are lost at this point in relation to f.

I hope I explained my point well. Feel free to ask if anything seems unclear.